# how to set cookies in cefsharp winform application?

Tags: winforms, cookies, cefsharp

I tried this code:

```
public static readonly CefSharp.Settings Settings = new CefSharp.Settings();
      public static void InitCef()
        {

            if (CEF.Initialize(Settings))
            {
                CEF.RegisterScheme("fs", new FsSchemeHandlerFactory());
                CEF.RegisterScheme("param", new ParamSchemeHandlerFactory());
                CEF.SetCookie(@"https://mydomen.com", "mydomen.com", "test", "test1", new DateTime(2100, 1, 1));
            }

        }
```

but no reaction. I don't know why. I read many posts and there weren't solution of my problem, nothing works. Please, help me.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: cefsharp: version  - 1.25, runtime version : 2.0

Comment: `CefSharp1` is so old, nobody maintains it anymore. You'll have to dig through the source, see if there's any examples. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/CefSharp1 If you have the option to upgrade to a newer version I'd take it. (Current version is `47.0.0`)